# Mysql union, left join, group and count

Tags: mysql, union

Heres my query

```
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id,
    fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id,
    fsi_transmittals.product_name,
    fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered
 LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing ON fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered.master_listing_id = fsi_master_listing.master_listing_id
 LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals ON fsi_master_listing.transmittal_id = fsi_transmittals.transmittal_id
 WHERE dispatch_code_id=".$this->db->escape($dispatch_code_id)."
```

`fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing` table

```
  master_listing_id   dispatch_code_id
          2                 2
          5                 2
          36                2
          37                2
          134               2
          135               2
          136               2
          137               2
          138               2
          139               2
          140               2
```

`fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered` table

```
  master_listing_id   dispatch_code_id
          1                 2
```

`fsi_master_listing` table

```
  master_listing_id   transmittal_id
          1                 1
          2                 1
          5                 2
          36                2
          37                2
          134               3
          135               3
          136               3
          137               3
          138               3
          139               3
          140               3
```

`fsi_transmittals` table

```
  transmittal_id   product_name
        1             Name 1
        2             Name 2
        3             Name 3
```

What Im trying to do is to get the combined result of product from `fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing` and `fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered` where dispatch_code_id='2' and count them

My desire Output would be

```
  Product Name    Product Count
     Name 1            2
     Name 2            3
     Name 3            7
```

Thanks in advance, hope somebody can help me to this..

Comment: So what is the problem with the query you posted?

Comment: Im stock on my query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, you just need to:

- Add `COUNT` with `GROUP BY product_name` and put your query as a subquery.
- The `transmittal_id` is specified two times in the two union queries, either remove one of them or give them different names (It might work fine in MySQL, but it is recommended not to do so).

So your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT
  t.product_name,
  COUNT(*) AS ProductCount
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ml.master_listing_id,
        m.transmittal_id,
        t.product_name
     FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing AS ml
     LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing AS m 
                                  ON ml.master_listing_id = m.master_listing_id
     LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals AS t 
                                ON m.transmittal_id = t.transmittal_id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
        u.master_listing_id,
        m.transmittal_id,
        t.product_name
     FROM fsi_courier_assignment_print_master_listing_undelivered as u 
     LEFT JOIN fsi_master_listing AS m 
                                  ON u.master_listing_id = m.master_listing_id
     LEFT JOIN fsi_transmittals AS t 
                                ON m.transmittal_id = t.transmittal_id
) AS t
GROUP BY t.product_name;
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: Ok Im gonna try this at home later, thanks a lot for your help :D